# Geoserver can't create reader for geotiff

Tags: geoserver, reader, geotiff

Geoserver 2.15 running in open shift from image oscarfonts/geoserver  with `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` mounted in a volume R/W doesn't create a geotiff reader (storage).

Trying to create a storage from a geotiff located on the mount volume gives the following error:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: 
Failed to create reader from file:TEST.tif

Hints: 
EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@23734df8[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] 
REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@78e50081 

System defaults: 
FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http 
FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true 
FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@3dec5ca6 
STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl 
LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true 
COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 
GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory 
TILE_ENCODING = null 
FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl
```

Tried with different tiff files and the error doesn't change, but creating a storage from a shapefile it works without any problems.

Any suggestions on how to debug the problem or what maybe causing it ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87384/creating-store-in-geoserver-using-imagemosaic-plugin-gives-error - see answer about hostname/IP lookup

Answer (score 0):

Using `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` (as a volume) under the tomcat folder and inside the geoserver solved the problem